# Repeated nested properties of StructuredProperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

While the NDB documentation says:

> Although a StructuredProperty can be repeated and a StructuredProperty can contain another StructuredProperty, beware: **if one structured property contains another, only one of them can be repeated**.

It appeared to me that the clearest interpretation of the documentation may be properly written as "if one structured property contains another structured property".

In which case, I would expect something like this to work:

```
class KeyList(ndb.Model):
  keys = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)

class Collection(ndb.Model):
  lists = ndb.StructuredProperty(KeyList, repeated=True)
```

However, this fails with the error:

> TypeError: This StructuredProperty cannot use repeated=True because its model class (KeyList) contains repeated properties (directly or indirectly).

It appears that one cannot nest *any* repeated property inside a repeated StructuredProperty.

From the code, this [looks to be the intended behaviour](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-python-vm-runtime/blob/master/python_vm_runtime/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py#L2238).

In which case the development appserver may differ from the documented behaviour. If the documentation as I've read it is correct, then a fix for [the condition in the development server giving rise to the above error](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-python-vm-runtime/blob/master/python_vm_runtime/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py#L2237) might be something like:

```
if modelclass._has_repeated and isinstance(modelclass, StructuredProperty):
   # ...
```

Should an AppEngine StructuredProperty be able to contain repeated properties (other than a repeated StructuredProperty)?

Issue report is here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-python-vm-runtime/issues/40

**EDIT**  It's worth noting that the [golang docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference) say this:

> Slices of structs are valid, as are structs that contain slices. However, if one struct contains another, then at most one of those can be repeated. This disqualifies recursively defined struct types: any struct T that (directly or indirectly) contains a []T.

The implication I take from this is that repeated non-struct properties on repeated structs are not inherently prohibited at the BigTable level, but rather a side-effect of the Python implementation.

Without further corroboration I would not rely on this implication.

Comment: I had the same problem and although the documentation says it's possible It is not.

Comment: Use LocalStructuredProperty instead. You can nest many levels. However be aware that's this propery will be stored as a blob.

Comment: @janscas As a blob, the properties of a LocalStructuredProperty cannot be indexed.

Comment: I know... But it,s the only way to nest models in the same entity

Comment: Documentation seems pretty clear.  If you want indexed structiured properties don't nest them.

Comment: @TimHoffman You have repeated the ambiguity that constitutes the essential crux of the question.  

Comment: My interpretation of `if one structured property contains another, only one of them can be repeated` took `one of them` to mean any property within the nesting not just StructuredProperties.

Comment: @TimHoffman Your interpretation is incorrect.  The rules of parallel English dictate that, in this case, "the "one" clearly encompasses the adjunct "structured" and parallels it into "an other.""  See http://english.stackexchange.com/q/300168/4061

Comment: I suggest you log a bug against the documentation with google.

Comment: Thanks @TimHoffman – a link to the issue is in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug with our documentation --

With `StructuredProperty`s, you can only have a single layer of repeated properties.

---

Some background:

ndb handles `StructuredProperty`s by exploding properties before writing to Datastore. So for example:

```
class Inner(ndb.Model):
  a = ndb.StringProperty()

class Outer(ndb.Model):
  inner = ndb.StructuredProperty(Inner, repeated=True)
```

Then if we write: `Outer(inner=[Inner(a="1"), Inner(a="2")])`, this actually gets written to the Datastore as:

```
{
  inner.a = ["1", "2"]
}
```

However, if instead `Inner.a` were repeated, we could write something like:

```
 Outer(inner=[Inner(a=["1", "3"]), Inner(a=["2", "4"])])
```

This would get written to Datastore like:

```
{
  inner.a : ["1", "3", "2", "4"]
}
```

Then when we read this, we have no idea how to parse, as all these are valid:

```
Outer(inner=[Inner(a=["1", "3"]), Inner(a=["2", "4"])])
Outer(inner=[Inner(a=["1", "3", "2"]), Inner(a=["4"])])
Outer(inner=[Inner(a=["1"]), Inner(a=["3"]), Inner(a=["2"]), Inner(a=["4"])])
Outer(inner=[Inner(a=[]), Inner(a=["1", "3", "2", "4"])])
```

Note that other libraries (for example Objectify) can avoid this issue by storing both the exploded properties for indexing and an unindexed blob of the entire dataset which can maintain the structure for deserialization.

Answer (score -1):

The documentation for structured properties clearly states:

> Although a StructuredProperty can be repeated and a StructuredProperty can contain another StructuredProperty, beware: if one structred property contains another, only one of them can be repeated. A work-around is to use LocalStructuredProperty, which does not have this constraint (but does not allow queries on its property values).